# Automaticly add module dependencies on gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've an weird behavior when using modules on gradle with Android Studio... it's kind complicated to explain so i think is better to give an example

Let say my application has two modules

`:bar`
`:foo`

`foo` uses `play-services-location` so I do import it on its build.gradle. `foo` compiles fine.

`bar` uses `foo`, so on `build.gradle` of bar's folder I do:
`api project(path: ':foo')`
`bar` also uses `play-services-location` but as `bar` imports `foo` i think it should transitivelly import `play-services-location` however if I don't explicit do
`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$location_library_version"`
bar doesn't compile

So am I missing something? Shouldn't it automaticly import all the dependency dependencies... so any transitive dependency be ready and I didn't need to re-import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 'api' (not 'implemenatation') for 'google-play-location' in 'foo', so it can be depended by 'bar' which uses 'foo'. And if there is no other modules which depends on 'bar', it is better to specify 'implementation foo' in 'bar', not 'api'